# How do I convert this into a comprehension? (Python)

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-2.x

This function produces the sum of the first n values, the sum of the second n values...etc.

Here is the function:

```
def collect_sum(iterable,n):
    for e in range(1,len(ite)+1):
        if e%n==0:
            yield sum(iterable[e-n:e])

for i in c_sum(range(1,21),5):
       print(i,end=' ')
```

This is supposed to return 15, 40, 65. When I use a list comprehension, it returns 0, 30, 40.

Comment: The code you show has a number of errors in it.

Comment: If your function is supposed to accept an iterable then you should not be doing len() on it since not all iterables have a defined length.

Comment: So what would be the better solution? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# generator version
def collect_sum(iterable,n):
  for e in range(1,len(iterable)+1):
    if e%n==0:
      yield sum(iterable[e-n:e])

# list comprehension version
def collect_sum(iterable,n):
  return [sum(iterable[e-n:e]) for e in range(1,len(iterable)+1) if e%n==0] 

for i in collect_sum(range(1,21),5):
  print(i,end=' ')
```

Comment: Oh damn I had what you had...accidently used the & operator. Wow I feel stupid.

Comment: Also @garlfd, if you can do `len` on it, it's not a general iterable, it's a _sequence_

Answer (score 2):

```
def collect_sum(i,n):
    return (sum(g) for (_,g ) in groupby(i,key=lambda _,c=count():floor(next(c)/n)))
for v in collect_sum(range(1,21),5):
    print(v)
```

Produces:

```
15
40
65
90
>>>
```

Comment: Close, but that returns a _generator expression_, not a _list comprehension_ ;)

Comment: I thought that would be nicer :|

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.islice`:

```
In [28]: n=5

In [29]: from itertools import islice

In [30]: lis=range(1,21)

In [31]: it=iter(lis)

In [33]: [sum(islice(it,n))  for _ in xrange(len(lis)/n) ]

Out[33]: [15, 40, 65, 90]
```